# How to parse a xml and read its values

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, windows-phone-8

i am using C# windows phone 8 and I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <login res="SUCCESS"  encstatus="DEFAULT" usedquota="0"  />
```

I need to extract the values of res, encstatus and usedQuota.

How do I do that in xml parsing?

I tried this

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
            var pol = xDoc.Element("res");
            var items = xDoc.Descendants("res");
```

Where str is the xml file, but all the elements are empty / null.

Comment: you want attributes, not elements

Comment: Yes may be in that way I can get the attributes value. Actually this is the response from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those nodes are attributes:

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(str)
 XElement login = xDoc.Root;
 string res = (string)login.Attribute("res");
 string encstatus = (string)login.Attribute("encstatus");
 int usedquota = (int)login.Attribute("usedquota");
```

Comment: Thanks ...  you helped me a lot. I didn't know this was so simple.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to get the *attribute* values, no element:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);

var pol = (string)xDoc.Root.Attribute("res");
```